# How can I enable the WYSIWYG editor to be on by default for just one module?

Tags: wysiwyg

I don't use the WySiWyG editor because it removes the formatting in CMS blocks and get to mangle {{ }} directives with image tags.

However my colleagues use a helpdesk module that is a paid for 'AheadWorks' module. They need the WySiWyG editor on by default.

The 'problem' is that they need the editor enabled by default whereas I need it disabled by default.

Is there any way of solving this in an easy way without having to learn another area of Magento code?